# VS402478- locked process templates issue

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Just trying to delete and re-upload new process templates but i'm getting a VS402478 error saying the template is locked.

[image]

Who or how were they locked and how do I unlock them?

I can't find anything on the VS402478 error online.

Comment: That's a new one on me.  Presumably you have sufficient privileges on the collection.  Are you running VS as an administrator?  Are you using the same version of VS as TFS?  Can any other admin perform the task?

Comment: @rerwinRR Ya, it is. I can't find a single person whose encountered this issue. Yes, I have full privileges, i've tried running as an admin and i'm using  tfs2013 update 4 with VS 2015. I'm solely doing the setup for the company i'm in and i'm currently the only user so i'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Just a thought but have you tried with Team Explorer 2013?  Could be a mismatch of VS and TFS versions

Comment: Just tried it there and no joy

Comment: Interestingly the default templates are now locked in TFS 2015 (and I can repro the error message) but I don't  get why you're seeing this on TFS 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but to clear this up for anyone who comes across this question, here is the answer:

> The templates are now locked, which means that you cannot make changes to the shipped templates. To create a custom process template based on a shipped template, simply export an existing template, give it a new name and version, and then reimport it by using the Process Template Manager. Existing projects are unaffected by this change, which means that they can continue to have their process customized by using witadmin

Source: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was using TFS 2013.4 with VS 2015.RTM and got this message as well. When I switched Visual Studio to VS 2013.5, it worked.