# TFS 2015: Version-Error uploading custom process template

Tags: tfs, guid, agile, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

I've created a customized process based on the Agile process and have already done all prescribed steps noted in this post: [TFS 2015 won't upload custom process template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999557/tfs-2015-wont-upload-custom-process-template) 
however when I change the version type to something different I receive this error during the upload process:

```
Time: 2016-04-21T08:37:48
Module: Template Importer
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (type WebException)Status: ProtocolError
Response Status Code: BadRequest
Response Status Message: VS402452: The process template did not specify a version, or specified an invalid version

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationProcessTemplateService.AddUpdateTemplate(String name, String description, String metadata, String state, String zipFileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.TemplateManagementService.UpLoadTemplateFile(TemplateData data, FileInfo templateZipFile, ELeadLogger log)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.TemplateManagementService.Import(String folderPath, ILogHandler logHandler)
```

Is there a list of 'acceptable' version types? The msdn documentation for TFS 2015 indicates that by uploading a customized process template it will not touch any of the existing processes, but this error seems to contradict that notion.

Any ideas? Been chomping away at this one for a day and everything else is ready to go once this one roadblock is cleared.  Thanks!

Comment: What version did you specify for the process template? In `ProcessTemplate.xml`, there's a `version` element that should look like this: `<version type="ADCC42AB-9882-485E-A3ED-7678F01F66BC" major="14" minor="1" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default templates have been locked with the release of TFS 2013 update 3 or 4. So now you'll need to change the type GUID to be unique for your template and the name.

You'll find the process template version in the `ProcessTemplate.xml` in the root of your Process Template folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProcessTemplate>
  <metadata>
    <name>Scrum 2015</name>
    <description>This template is for teams who follow the Scrum framework.</description>
    <version type="6B724908-EF14-45CF-84F8-768B5384DA46" major="3" minor="33" />
    <plugins>
    ...
  ... 
...
```

If your template doesn't have this tag already, you'll need to add it.

If you create a custom template you must also [override the GUID and the name with your own values and that should get you onlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319817/736079).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProcessTemplate>
  <metadata>
    <!-- new name -->
    <name>Custom Scrum 2015</name>
    <description>This template is for teams who follow the Scrum framework.</description>
    <!-- add/override version and set a new guid -->
    <version type="276d0f20-c2f9-4077-8199-e81a8cc47012" major="1" minor="0" />
    <plugins>
    ...
  ... 
...
```