# can't upload custom process template in Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm trying to create a custom process template in Azure DevOps Server 2020. I'm using the on-premises XML process model. When I upload my custom process template I keep getting 'You can't update a system process' error.

These are the steps I took:

1. Downloaded the Agile system process by going to Collection Settings->Process, clicking on Agile and choosing 'Export'.
2. I unzipped the downloaded folder and opened it in Visual Studio.
3. I made changes to field names and added new states for bugs.
4. I changed the name and version in the ProcessTemplate.xml like so:

```
<metadata>
<name>CustomProcess</name>
<description>This is a custom process template based on the Agile process</description>
<version type="ADCC42AB-9882-485E-A3ED-7678F01F66BC" major="1" minor="0" />
```

5. I renamed the folder to CustomProcess and zipped it.
6. In Collection Settings->Process, I clicked on 'Upload process template' and tried to upload my CustomProcess zipped folder. I get the error 'You can't update a system process'.

I made sure to update the name and version as suggested in a previous Stackoverflow post but I still get an error. Is there something else I need to modify in the XML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at some more related Stackoverflow posts and found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776244/2026659) helpful. The issue was I need to generate a new GUID for the version. I went into Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Create GUID. Choose the number 6 option for the GUID format. Paste the GUID into the version type: `<version type="[paste GUID here]" major="1" minor="0" />`

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar issue. The official documentation doesn't mention any of this which is very disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/310354/cant-upload-a-custom-process-template-to-tfs-2018.html

> You have to change the name and the version of the template

Comment: I did change the version and the name as I previously mentioned. I figured it out. I had to generate a new GUID for the version.